# c# how do you use a loop to repeat a stage in an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, foreach

I stored some questions in an array for user to answer but I don't want the user to enter an integer. At the moment when user enters integer it says "please enter a word ", then it skips to the next question. I want it to repeat the question until the user enters a word and then continue with the loop.

I just started learning c# recently any help would be much appreciated.

```
            string [] Ques = new string [5];
            Ques[0] = "How do you say Good morning  in Portuguese";
            Ques[1] = "how do you say how are you;";
            Ques[2] = "how do you say I am fine thank you";
            Ques[3] = "How do you say is everything ok";
            Ques[4] = "how do you say yes";

            foreach (string Q in Ques)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Q);
                string Answer = Console.ReadLine();
                int value;
                if (int.TryParse(Answer, out value))

                {
                    Console.WriteLine("please enter a word");

                } 


            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a while loop inside your for:

```
string[] Ques = new string[5];
Ques[0] = "How do you say Good morning  in Portuguese";
Ques[1] = "how do you say how are you;";
Ques[2] = "how do you say I am fine thank you";
Ques[3] = "How do you say is everything ok";
Ques[4] = "how do you say yes";

foreach (string Q in Ques)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Q);
    string Answer = Console.ReadLine();
    int value;
    while (int.TryParse(Answer, out value))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("please enter a word");
        Answer = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

This way, for each question while the user enters an integer, he prompts "please enter a word", and it continues until he enters an string than can not be parsed to int, then next question will be promped.

Comment: Thanks for that, i only started using stackoverflow today.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to move to the next element while iterating, don't use a `foreach`, use a simple `for` and control your progress:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Ques.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Q);
    string Answer = Console.ReadLine();
    int value;
    if (int.TryParse(Answer, out value))
    {
         Console.WriteLine("please enter a word");
         i--; // go back, and will go forward in for statement
    } 
}
```

Obviously, your code is incomplete, since you're not doing anything with `Answer`. When you change it to be meaningful, you might find other solutions more suitable.

Comment: thanks,  i got it to work. i  don't know why i used foreach loop first instead of for loop, but they both worked.

Comment: Both will work, and `foreach` is more concise, but it has its downsides

Answer (score 0):

> I want it to repeat the question until the user enters a word and then
>   continue

Sounds like you need another loop:

```
foreach (string Q in Ques)
{
    bool numberEntered = false;
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Q);
        string Answer = Console.ReadLine();
        int value;
        numberEntered = int.TryParse(Answer, out value);
        if (numberEntered)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("please enter a word");
        }
    }
    while (numberEntered);
}
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it works great. thanks for your help. now am going to test other methods suggested by others.

Comment: @Edwete123 glad I could help; that's a great approach to learning, go ahead :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (it repeats the questions)

```
 string[] Ques = new string[5];
        Ques[0] = "How do you say Good morning  in Portuguese";
        Ques[1] = "how do you say how are you;";
        Ques[2] = "how do you say I am fine thank you";
        Ques[3] = "How do you say is everything ok";
        Ques[4] = "how do you say yes";

        foreach (string Q in Ques)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(Q);
            string Answer = Console.ReadLine();
            int value;
            if (!int.TryParse(Answer, out value))
            {
                while (!int.TryParse(Answer, out value))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("please enter a word");
                    Console.WriteLine(Q);
                    Answer = Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
```